# Downloading source code in Trac

Tags: plugins, download, trac

I'm not able to directly download some source files from my project using Trac.

I understand that it's possible to use a SCM client, like git or svn to do this, but surely it can be done without leaving Trac!

Do I need some plug-in, or is there a command or configuration that I've missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a plugin for this.  When using the Repository Browser, look for a "Download In Other Formats" link at the bottom of pages.  Individual files will have an "Original Format" link that lets you download the original file, and folders will have a "Zip Archive" link to download the entire folder.

**Update:**

Also, make sure that you have Trac configured with the repository paths that you want to make downloadable.  In trac.ini, look for a property named `downloadable_paths` in the `[browser]` section.  The repository paths listed here (and only those listed here) will be made available for download through the web interface.  For example, my trac.ini has the following:

```
[browser]
downloadable_paths = /trunk, /branches/*, /tags/*
```

For more information about this configuration parameter, see the [official Trac documentation](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracIni#browser-section) for trac.ini.

Comment: This is weird. This option doesn't show up here, only when I open a file or a diff. If it is useful to know, I'm using git as version control system. Is there any difference from subversion at this point?

Comment: The version control system in use shouldn't matter, this should be purely a Trac thing.  What version of Trac are you using?

Comment: It's probably a Trac configuration issue.  See my updated answer for details.

Comment: This is the answer, but not It is not yet supported on Trac. I gives me an error: "supported in git_fs".

Thank you very much, anyway :-)